# 'onSendError()' method in FirebaseMessagingService class does not invoked

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I'm using node js push notification to all user's tokens.
But when I send list of empty tokens , I can see the log in the firebase cloud functions print an error, but still "`OnSendError()`" of android `FirebaseMessagingService` class does not invoke. 
How come?

Answer (score 1):

[onSendError()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/FirebaseMessagingService.html#onSendError(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Exception)) is invoked when there is an error sending an **upstream** message [from a client to an XMPP server](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/upstream).  It is not invoked for failures related to a downstream message sent from a server to clients.